Can I change my hostname, URL of gitlab-ce server on Synology NAS?
I built a internal gitlab-ce server on my Synology NAS. I'm not good for using docker, so I just installed by GUI of Container Manager. The configure of Container manager is following.
Container configure
I didn't set the external url and hostname. I want to connect with url $(IP):4203. Because, $(IP) is aleady used for NAS access. Anyway, the server built up and running. 
But, there are two problems. First of these is that the GUI uses HOSTNAME as the URL, not IP.
I use this url http://$(IP):4203 for accessing, git push, pull, etc. But GUI show this.
URL on gitlab GUI
Users on my server are confused, but so far there are no functional issues.
But, there is a fatal problem. When I use gitlab-runner for creating the documentation page, gitlab-runner can't identify differences of URL
Running with gitlab-runner 17.1.0 (fe451d5a)
  on gitlab-runner P7Wu1kFhZ, system ID: r_eLt3UPK3OyGO
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:27
Using Docker executor with image continuumio/miniconda3 ...
Pulling docker image continuumio/miniconda3 ...
Using docker image sha256:715691c89b3515a6e607a9605b1207182ceb34843f07e639ec98ebe88f5ffdf8 for continuumio/miniconda3 with digest continuumio/miniconda3@sha256:0fe3d011c129245af1f631d19c6b7c4f34b61650c1c7881980f266cdaa44ed1b ...
Preparing environment
00:09
Running on runner-p7wu1kfhz-project-19-concurrent-0 via fa4e6db0c6eb...
Getting source from Git repository
00:09
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/hyunbin-kang/IUPAN_dev/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'http://277e481265f1/hyunbin-kang/IUPAN_dev.git/': Could not resolve host: 277e481265f1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

The best fix is changing my URL. But when I edit exteranl url of my gitlab.rb file, it becomes impossible to access the server at all.
The next best thing is to specify the URL when gitlab-runner is running.
Any advice would be gratefully received. Thank you. Change external url 'http://$(IP):4203'. But it becomes worse. Set env variable GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG:'external_url "http://$(IP):4203". But it becomes worse.
